# Get computers currently using my winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Can someone give me some ideas on how I can achieve this?

I want to have a monitoring application that lists the computer name and ip address of the computers that has my winform application currently open, of course the computer name and ip should disappear when they close the application.

I thought of just using a database table that I update when my application starts or closes but this would give me problems if the application is terminated abnormally and the table isn't updated.

I'm looking at a real time monitoring here, if I open the monitoring application then I get all PCs running the application, the list is then update at X intervals.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you disclose what kind of application you are developing? Just high level architecture. Because there can be other better approach to do it and somebody can suggest you that.

Comment: "this would give me problems if the application is terminated abnormally and the table isn't updated." I think you'll have this problem no matter how you do it. A computer could just lose power! The best you can do is have a "heartbeat" message that's sent at a certain rate, and if you haven't received it in a while then the client's presumed disconnected. (This could be implemented for you depending on how you're doing networking.)

Comment: @vnikhil no particular application, I have multiple winforms application in c# and vb.net and I just want to monitor if it's currently being used or not.

Comment: @31eee384 what's the best way to achieve your suggestion?

Comment: Well the *easiest* way would probably be to have the application send a `POST` to a web server you control every, say, two minutes. Then on that server you keep track of the requests in a database and your reporting app reads from that however it wants. On the server you want to allow for more than two minutes between heartbeats though in case they're delayed or can't be completed. As for which technologies to use, that's really up to you. This is a really broad area.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) to update status with interval of time.
2. Use the following code to detect IP Address

   ```
   private static string GetIpAddress()
   {
       string localIP = "?";
       var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
       foreach (var ip in host.AddressList.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
       {
           localIP = ip.ToString();
       }
       return localIP;
   }
   ```
3. To get Computer Name

   ```
   var name = Environment.MachineName;
   ```
4. To detect System is going to Shut Down while application running background and need to update status

   ```
   private bool _systemShutdown;
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
   {
       if (m.Msg == WmQueryendSession)
       {
           _systemShutdown = true; // call here method to update status
       }
       base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
   ```
5. To detect LAN status, Unplugged or connected

   ```
   NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged;

   using Microsoft.Win32;

   private void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
   {            
       _connectionStatus = !e.IsAvailable ? ConnectionStatus.Unplugged : ConnectionStatus.Connected;
   }
   ```
6. Get Last Machine Login Time

   ```
   private static DateTime? GetLastLoginToMachine(string machineName, string userName)
   {
       try
       {
           var c = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, machineName);
           using (var uc = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(c, userName))
           {
               if (uc != null) return uc.LastLogon;
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           ExceptionLogger.CreateFile(ex);
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
7. Set application to Run at Startup

   ```
   private void RunWindowsStartup(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var menuItem = ((MenuItem)(sender));
       menuItem.Checked = !menuItem.Checked;
       RegisterInStartup(menuItem.Checked);
   }
   private static void RegisterInStartup(bool isChecked)
   {
       try
       {
           var appName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Split('.')[0];
           using (var registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
           {
               if (registryKey == null) return;
               if (isChecked)
               {
                   registryKey.SetValue(appName, Application.ExecutablePath);
               }
               else
               {
                   registryKey.DeleteValue(appName);
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           ExceptionLogger.CreateFile(ex);
           TlMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", TlMessageBoxButtons.OK, TlMessageBoxIcon.Error, ex.StackTrace);
       }
   }
   ```
8. Get Active InActive (Idle) Time

   ```
   [DllImport("User32.dll")]
   public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
   [DllImport("User32.dll")]
   private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO Dummy);
   public static uint GetIdleTime()
   {
       var LastUserAction = new LASTINPUTINFO();
       LastUserAction.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(LastUserAction);
       GetLastInputInfo(ref LastUserAction);
       return ((uint)Environment.TickCount - LastUserAction.dwTime);
   }
   internal struct LASTINPUTINFO
   {
       public uint cbSize;
       public uint dwTime;
   }

   // Use System.Windows.Form.Timer Tick event for further calculations ...
   ```